# phantomjs memory leaks and restarting casperjs

Tags: bash, phantomjs, casperjs

Due to some well known bugs in phantomjs regardying memory leaks I am trying to create a bash script to restart my casperjs/phantomjs stuff when phantomjs crashes.....

```
cmd1="casperjs testCasper.js" 

until $cmd1 >>$2; do
    echo "Server $cmd1 crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.." 
    echo `killall phantomjs` 
    sleep 5
done
```

But somehow the phantomjs crashes dont get noticed and `$cmd1 >>$2;` have always the exit code of 0.

Does anyone have a working restarting casperjs script?

Thanks,